# c++ constructor malfunctioning

Tags: c++, qt, constructor

I am trying to program a qt widget application which deals with linked list of nodes, the node contains 3 char* data member and 2 int members and a "next" pointer of "node" type,
my issue is the char* members in nodes of the linked list are getting saved same as the third char* member, I tried using debugger and found out that
the length of all the 3 ints i.e. lentitl,lenpub,lenpub are initialized to same value, and all the 3 char* members are getting same value,
the node constructor is as follows

```
node::node(char* titl,char* auth,char* pub,int pri,int stockp)
{    

    int lentitl,lenauth,lenpub;
    lenpub=strlen(pub);
    lentitl=strlen(titl);
    lenauth=strlen(auth);


    title=new char[lentitl+1];
    author=new char[lenauth+1];
    publisher=new char[lenpub+1];
    strcpy(title,titl);
    strcpy(author,auth);
    strcpy(publisher,pub);

    price=pri;
    stockposition=stockp;
    next=NULL;
}
```

the node functions if called from another class function named "addbook",and addbook is called from mainwindow.cpp, the functions calls for addbook is as follows

```
void MainWindow::on_addbook_clicked()
{
    char *titl,*auth,*pub;
    int pri,stockp;

    titl=ui->title->toPlainText().toLatin1().data();
    auth=ui->author->toPlainText().toLatin1().data();
    pub=ui->publisher->toPlainText().toLatin1().data();
    pri=ui->price->toPlainText().toInt();
    stockp=ui->stockposition->toPlainText().toInt();
    p.addbook(titl,auth,pub,pri,stockp);

}
```

and the function call for node is as follows

```
void shop::addbook( char *titl, char *auth, char *pub, int pri, int stockp)
    {    
    node *p=new node(titl,auth,pub,pri,stockp);
    if(start==NULL)
        {
        start=p;
        end=p;
        }
    else
        {
        p->next=start;
        start=p;
        }    
    }
```

the zip of whole project is [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6C89B7CD0BEA397F%21803)
and [here](https://s16.postimg.org/6iw4mdy2t/image.png) is the link to the ouput

the screen shot of the output is [image: here]

as you can see in the image,string entered at "publisher" textedit is getting set to all 3 char* of the node,
can anyone explain me why is this happening?

Comment: ui->title == ui->author == ui->publisher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
titl=ui->title->toPlainText().toLatin1().data();
```

This is probably the issue: `toLatin1()` returns a new `QByteArray` which owns its data. You assign the internal data pointer of that `QByteArray` to `titl`. However, the `QByteArray` is only a temporary variable and will get destroyed in the next line of code. When the `QByteArray` gets destroyed, it will free its data, which means your `titl` is now pointing to memory that was already freed - i.e. `titl` points to an invalid memory location.

Suggested solution alternatives:

1. Use `QString` instead of `char*` in your node class, much easier to deal with memory management issues that way
2. Make sure your `QByteArray` temporary lives as long as you need the data (until you `strcpy` the data):

   QByteArray titl = ui->title->toPlainText().toLatin1();
   QByteArray auth = ui->author->toPlainText().toLatin1();
   QByteArray pub = ui->publisher->toPlainText().toLatin1();
   pri=ui->price->toPlainText().toInt();
   stockp=ui->stockposition->toPlainText().toInt();
   p.addbook(titl.data(),auth.data(),pub.data(),pri,stockp);

Comment: i was thinking of using Qstrings everywhere as 'last resort',hence i didn't use it in the constructor.
Anyways
thank you, that worked!

Comment: @Anuj Is there a reason you're avoiding `QString`?

Comment: yes,i wanted to learn the conversions so avoiding  qstrings and yes they are very easy to work with

Answer (score 2):

I'm not expert of Qt but there is something that doesn't sound good to me in terms of C++. Mainly a function in your code is returning a "char * " pointer instead of a "const char*", I'm talking about these lines:

```
   char *titl,*auth,*pub;
    int pri,stockp;

    titl=ui->title->toPlainText().toLatin1().data();
```

If the data was directly provided by the title class I expect to obtain a const char* pointer in order to do not be allowed to modify it. The only reason you can handle a char* ( or in other words a well known library is designed to return a non const pointer) is that there is a temporary object or a static buffer in the middle of the calls: toLatin1 or data.

Reading the docs of Qt: toLatin1 is returning a temporary object, a QByteArray.

```
QByteArray  toLatin1 () const
```

for more information: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html

So simply modify each string request like:

```
QByteArray titlArray = ui->title->toPlainText().toLatin1();
titl=titlArray.data();
```

in that way each string will point to a still existing buffer when you are calling

```
  p.addbook(titl,auth,pub,pri,stockp);
```